# Resultado do loop paginado ao invés de unificado

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Estou com dificuldades na hora de pegar um resultado formatado em JSON paginado. Meu código ao invés de retornar o resultado do for unido, está trazendo o resultado por página!

```
import requests

def __init__(self, usuario, token):
    self.usuario = usuario
    self.token = token

def get_json(self, url):
    retorno = requests.get(url, auth=(self.usuario, self.token))
    if retorno.status_code != 200:
        print('Status:', retorno.status_code, 'Problem with the request. Exiting.')
        exit()

    return retorno.json()

def get_list_url(self, url):
    lista_url = [url]
    json_retorno = self.get_json(url)

    while json_retorno['next_page'] is not None:
        lista_url.append(json_retorno['next_page'])
        json_retorno = self.get_json(json_retorno['next_page'])
    return lista_url

def imprime_lista(self, url):
    json_retorno = self.get_json(url)
    resolvidos_30d = 0
    limite = 30
    data_atual = datetime.strptime('2018-06-06', '%Y-%m-%d')

    for res in json_retorno['tickets']:
        if res['dates']['solved_at'] is not None:
            solved_at = res['dates']['solved_at'][:10]
            data_resolvido = datetime.strptime(solved_at, '%Y-%m-%d')
            quantidade_dias = abs((data_atual - data_resolvido).days)
            if quantidade_dias <= limite:
                resolvidos_30d = resolvidos_30d + 1
            elif quantidade_dias > limite:
                break

        print(id, resolvidos_30d, sep=';')

tickets = ['2720018']
urlTrigger = 'exemplo.com.br'
api = login('1@2.com /token', 'xxx')

for id in tickets:
    role_znd = id
    lista = api.get_list_url(urlTrigger+str(role_znd+'/includes'))

    for url in lista:
        api.imprime_lista(url)
```

Ele me retorna mais ou menos assim...

```
2720018;51
2720018;1
2720018;0
2720018;0

Process finished with exit code -1
```

Outro detalhe básico é que o break não é respeitado, estou fazendo errado?

Comment: Você não chama o método `get_list_url` em nenhum lugar? Se é ela que retorna a lista de todas as URLs, como fez para retornar todas as páginas juntas?

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Anderson, eu chamo ele lá embaixo, eu tinha tirado esse trecho do código aqui no stack (já adicionei novamente). Estou sem pista algum do porque ele retorna na página 1 51 depois página 2 1 resultado e por ai vai.

Comment: Obs.: Aceito dicas para deixar o código mais limpo ou eficiente... Estou aprendendo Python ainda e qualquer dica é valiosa para a evolução do meu aprendizado :)